# SQL Server: use CONTAINS in where of CTE

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, common-table-expression, contains, sql-server-2016

I have a regular `Select` statement and I use the `CONTAINS` method. It works after I defined a full-text index for the table.

Now I need the same thing in a CTE that include this table, but I still get the error for the full-text index that I need to configure.

> Cannot use a CONTAINS or FREETEXT predicate on column 'column' because it is not full-text indexed.

How do I do that on the fly with a CTE?

The only way I was able to define the full-text index for the table was with the ssms option and not the T-SQL command

Comment: @PeterB can you explain?

Comment: Please show the query that works, and the CTE that doesn't, and the definition of the index.

Comment: The problem is not the CTE, it's the column you are trying to apply the `CONTAINS` function. It doesn't have a full text index on it (indexes apply on a column, not on the full table).

Answer (score 0):

A possible work around would be to create a temporary table in the T-SQL command and then create the full-text index on the table.

Essentially replace:

```
WITH CTE
AS
(
    <select statement>
)
```

to:

```
<select clause>
INTO #TempTable
<from clause>
```

You can now create full-text index on the #TempTable and then use it in your T-SQL script. The table's scope is limited to the T-SQL script and hence you don't have to worry about deleting it (unless there is a memory constraint, of course). This is [quick reference](http://gyanendushekhar.com/2016/10/04/temporary-tables-sql-server/) for temporary tables in SQL Server, unable to find the official documentation for some reason.